# Pandas dataframe apply function to create new column based on selected row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am trying to generate a new column in a dataframe that is equal to the current rows index minus the index of the row originally selected by a user. Say we have this dataframe:

```
     A    B C
0  foo  bar  
1  bar  foo  
2  foo  bar
```

and our user has selected row 1. I want the values of column C to be this:

```
    A    B   C
0  foo  bar -1
1  bar  foo  0
2  foo  bar  1
```

I already know this can sort of be implemented by iterating through the dataframe using something like this:

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    df['C'].loc[index] = index - USER_SELECTED_INDEX
```

however this is very slow. So slow in fact that it doesn't work.

My question is, how can I use df.apply to speed things up? And how can I pass the index of the current row to my function that is being applied? I want to do something like:

```
def applyCol(index):
    df['C'].loc[index] = index - USER_SELECTED_INDEX

df['C'] = df.apply(applyCol, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer I was looking for. For those interested:

```
def applyCol(row):
    return row.name - USER_SELECTED_INDEX #row.name resolves to the index

df['C'] = df.apply(applyCol, axis=1)
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try this.

```
df.assign(C=df.index-1)
Out[28]: 
     A    B  C
0  foo  bar -1
1  bar  foo  0
2  foo  bar  1
```